# Pytesseract questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

I'm trying to read numbers from a screenshot I'm taking from a game, but I'm having a trouble getting the numbers right.

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui as pg
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
import threading
import cv2
import numpy
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import *
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'D:\Python\Tesseract\tesseract.exe'

    #configs
    custom_config = r'--dpi 300 --psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789' 

    # 1. load the image as grayscale
    img = cv2.imread("price.png",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    # Change all pixels to black, if they aren't white already (since all characters were white)
    img[img <= 150] = 231
    img[img == 199] = 0
    cv2.imwrite('resultfirst.png', img)
    # 2. Scale it 10x
    scaled = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=10, fy=10, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    # 3. Retained your bilateral filter
    filtered = cv2.bilateralFilter(scaled, 11, 17, 17)
    # 4. Thresholded OTSU method
    thresh = cv2.threshold(filtered, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    time.sleep(1)
    # 5. Erode the image to bulk it up for tesseract
    kernel = numpy.ones((5,5),numpy.uint8)
    eroded = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations = 2)
    pre_processed = eroded
    
    output = pytesseract.image_to_string(pre_processed, config=custom_config)
    
    cv2.imwrite('result.png', pre_processed)
    print(output)
```

[image: Image of numbers]

Image is pretty clear but returns either 13500 or 18500, but no amount of tinkering returns the 7 correctly. Is there a better way to go at it or am I forgetting something?

EDIT:

I managed to get better results after I converted the yellow (gray after grayscale conversion) to black, to fill the numbers. I added the conversion code to the codeblock.

Before:
[This was the original result before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MFPW.png)
After:
[This is the result now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F46J4.png)

Problem is that pytesseract still returns that 7 as 1 every time. I don't think I can make that 7 more like 7 from this.. what to do?

Comment: You're hardcoding in the region - are you sure you're not cutting off any of the 7?

Comment: @rassar Yes, the region is just for the screenshot (to cut away any unnecessary clutter that could confuse the tesseract) , the image I have posted here is the result, no cutting off.

Comment: Interesting, I get the same result. I'll take a look.

Comment: @rassar I edited the main post with new results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how general this solution will be, but if all of your pictures are like this one a threshold of 103 will work:

```py
image = cv2.imread('price.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

threshold = 103
_, img_binarized = cv2.threshold(gray, threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img_binarized, config='--dpi 300 --psm 6 --oem 1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789').strip())
```

gives `78500` on my machine.

Comment: Oh, that looks way simpler than what I have been doing, I'll give it a try! @rassar